# Backed by a Benjamin, What am I?

Tags: riddle

Backed by a Benjamin,

Used as an insult: I just can't win.

You might be surprised to find rocks in me,

Just as shocked as when you find me in a tree.

I can get high when I get wild,

But making you nod is more my style.

I am dark and I am light;

cold tomorrow but hot tonight.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Turkey.

Explanation:

Backed by a Benjamin,

> Benjamin Franklin is known for supporting the turkey as the national bird over the eagle. [This may just be urban legend. However he definitely preferred the turkey over the eagle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_turkey#Benjamin_Franklin_and_the_National_Bird_Suggestion)

Used as an insult: I just can't win.

You might be surprised to find rocks in me,

> Turkeys swallow rocks to help the gizzard digest food: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gizzard

Just as shocked as when you find me in a tree.

> Turkeys sleep in trees to avoid predators

I can get high when I get wild,

> Wild turkeys can fly

But making you nod is more my style.

> Tryptophan in turkey meat caused drowsiness (nodding off)

I am dark and I am light;

> Turkey is made up of dark meat and light meat

cold tomorrow but hot tonight.

> On Thanksgiving it is served hot, but often leftovers are cold the next day

Comment: Ah, clever. I think it refers to tryptophan

Comment: Correct! @Raystafarian yes: originally I thought to put "making you nod off" but thought that was too easy a clue...

Comment: Can we have a fuller explanation? I understand the tryptophan but ...

Comment: @AE   I edited this answer.. should be available after peer review...

Comment: Wow, you need an awful lot of knowledge to solve this riddle! Are you a professional turkeyologist or something?

Comment: @randal'thor, hard puzzles are good. I'm sure it's all on wikipedia. :)

Comment: @randal'thor Leslie answered it in just over half an hour... maybe not hard enough!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I had no idea about the tryptophan, that's pretty cool. (The Benjamin hint was what tipped me off, by the way. Great riddle!)

Answer (score 3):

> Lightning?

I don't get the rocks though, so maybe I'm wrong. Wait, yes I do.

> Hail

Comment: Oh, Ben Franklin and the kite.

Comment: This is an interesting guess, but on the wrong track. I am careful to make every word/line fit the answer, even if some bits require esoteric knowledge.

Comment: @DigitalChris rats!

Answer (score 2):

Oy vey,  here goes...

> EDM Rave! (music style and culture - electronic dance music event)

Backed by a Benjamin,

> EDM raves are a booming business and cost money to put on.  Benjamin is a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang_terms_for_money

Used as an insult: I just can't win.

> Lyrics in some EDM / Techo music contains slurs against homosexuals, black people, women, and just whatever you name it.  There is even insult style lyrics directed to insult pretty much anyone.  You can't win, because it's already in the lyrics, no matter what you say the song is already made and you can't change its course.

You might be surprised to find rocks in me,

> Some EDM has elements Rock-N-Roll.  You could also say it "Rocks"

Just as shocked as when you find me in a tree.

> People often climb trees during outdoor EDM events.  First time you see this, you might be quite shocked :P

I can get high when I get wild,

> Some people definitely get high and wild during music events.

But making you nod is more my style.

> People nod to the music

I am dark and I am light;

> Raves often feature dark spaces.  They also feature strobe lighting - flashes of light and then darkness.

cold tomorrow but hot tonight.

> Music is hot tonight - everybody is active, and dancing, but tomorrow you are out cold possibly with a hangover

Comment: Only line that is debatable is "Used as an insult" - other than that, I like this answer :)